# Translate the text of a textarea and store it in another textarea (without API)

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>
<body>
  <textarea id="textetrad" rows="5"></textarea>
  <textarea id="translated-text" rows="5"></textarea>
  <button id="run-translation" onclick="runTranslation();">Translate</button>
  <script>
    function runTranslation() {
      var data = document.getElementById("textetrad").value;
      var trad = LanguageApp.translate(data, 'en', 'es');
      document.getElementById("translated-text").value = trad;
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hello, I am creating a bar lateral and I have a problem. I would like to create a textarea where we insert what we want and it is translated in another textarea. I have tried different methods like `LanguageApp.translate(data , 'en', 'es')` but I can't get this function to work in the HTML code.
So already is what I want possible without using an API?
If yes, should I do it only in the HTML code or should I make the HMTL code and the .gs communicate?
And then how do I transmit the translation from the gs code to the HTML?

Comment: There are no native human language translators in browsers, if that's what you're after. Maybe you could get the API to work, if you just loaded it to the page?

Comment: LanguageApp is only for GoogleApps. Use the translate api

Comment: @Teemu I know that there is just the LanguageApp.translate function that translates but it only works in .gs I guess and not in HMTL?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/translate/

Comment: This is possible. Please take a moment to read the [HTML Service: Communicate with Server Functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication) guide. If you have questions after reading that and trying to implement what it describes, then please update/post a new question.

Comment: It is not possible without an API. You could not even get the value of the textarea without an API.

Answer (score 0):

I tried and made it work on apps script using `LanguageApp`

#### index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
  </head>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function runTranslation() {
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).translate(document.getElementById('textetrad').value);
    }

    function onSuccess(data) {
      document.getElementById('translated-text').value = data;
    }
  </script>

  <body>
    <textarea id="textetrad" rows="5"></textarea>
    <textarea id="translated-text" rows="5"></textarea>
    <button id="run-translation" onclick="runTranslation();">Translate</button>
  </body>

</html>
```

#### Code.gs:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
}

function translate(textValue){
  // automatically identify the language, then translate to spanish
  return LanguageApp.translate(textValue, '', 'es');
}
```

#### Process:

- upon `onclick`, execute `runTranslation`.
- when `translate` function (in Code.gs) runs with no issue, proceed with `onSuccess`
- passing the translated data, assign it to the other element

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Reference:

- [HTML Service: Communicate with Server Functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)